# alternatives for OAuth, SAML, OpenID Connect, and WebAuthn

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, saml, webauthn

I'm currently working on my thesis and facing the challenge of identifying the right authentication and authorization technologies.

Besides well-known solutions like OAuth, OpenID Connect, and WebAuthn, I'm searching for alternative approaches that excel in security and best case in user experience.
Could you recommend some of these alternatives or share insights from your own experience?

Answer (score 1):

I would maybe take a look at the [OpenID Foundation](https://openid.net/developers/specs/) for a bunch of specifications. Some of these are used in industries that protect high worth data, such as banking and medical, where strict security profiles are used.

The base ingredients are as follows:

- Enabling client applications to get an unforgeable API credential that can be locked down and customised according to business requirements
- Dealing with user accounts, authentication and registration in a flexible way, which works for any type of client application
- An architecture that externalises such complexity from application code

An interesting recent development is the move towards [decentralized identities and verifiable credentials](https://openid.net/specs/openid-4-verifiable-credential-issuance-1_0.html). This should enable seamless wallet based user identification, where the user can also restrict which personal information they reveal.

The tendency these days is to implement such initiatives in terms of OAuth and OIDC, so that newer security features are layered on top of the base ingredients.